Why isn't my iframe showing in my HTML code?
I'm working on a web project where I have an iframe that should display a specific webpage, but for some reason, it's not showing up. Here's a simplified version of my HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Meta tags and CSS links -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navbar and other content -->

    <!-- Code for iframe -->
    <div class="relative mx-auto container px-6">
        <div class="relative">
            <!-- Background elements -->
            <div class="absolute inset-0 -top-3 bg-gradient-to-r from-violet-600 to-indigo-600 rounded-xl transform -rotate-1 origin-bottom-left"></div>
            <div class="relative rounded-xl shadow-md h-full bg-white">
                <div id="demo-container" class="flex flex-col rounded-lg shadow-xl overflow-hidden h-full bg-gray-900">
                    <div class="shrink-0 flex items-center bg-gray-950 py-2 px-4 z-10">
                        <!-- Navbar indicators -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-grow overflow-y-auto relative z-10">
                        <iframe class="absolute inset-0 w-full h-full" src="/schedule"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

However, despite setting the src attribute of the iframe to "/schedule", the iframe is not displaying the content it should. I've checked the source URL ("/schedule") separately, and it loads fine, so I'm unsure why it's not working within the iframe. Any insights into what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.
im also using tailwind css
Full Code if Necessary:
https://codepen.io/Avisator4/pen/XWQyNQE

its likely that position absolute is the cause

Yes, but if i take it out everything looks so glitched.

it looks normal here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/. Can you elaborate what kind of "glitchy" look you are getting?

so im like using the same exact code as their using in this section of the website, but for some reason there using the absolute class, but there iframe is showing.
use inspect element on https://savvycal.com/home @TanishqS

neither does removing the absolute effects their iframe, moreover they've got a relative parent

oh @Yogi how do i fix that

essentially the result on savvycal.com

@Yogi https://savvycal.com/home

It fixes when you remove the position absolute or adding position relative to its parent from the iframe element.
This would be the snippet:
<iframe class="inset-0 w-full h-full" src="/schedule"></iframe>
Output:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/OJgfAkrujI

ok that makes more sense, but why isnt the full width of the iframe showing like it shows on the savvycal website.
here is my current code: https://play.tailwindcss.com/7KVxwxpJaP
Image of what i mean: https://imgur.com/a/K1AFYgL

it shows the iframe to have full width to me..

idk why its like that for me

try adding w-full to the iframe and its parent. https://play.tailwindcss.com/ikeDzBhFZY

still same problem. bruhhh idk why its doing that
